# Executar query sql

Tags: php, sql

```
$sql = "exec atualizar_feira '".$nome."', '".$endereco."', '".$cep."', '".$escolaridade."', '".$instituicao."', '".$telefone."', '".$email."', '".$aluno_cairu."', '".$curso."', '".$curso2."', '".$palestra."', '".$data."' ";

$result = mssql_query($sql);
```

Como faço para executar essa $sql?

Comment: msql_query????
Faz tempo que não uso isso por que migrei para o PDO, mas se não me falha a memória é `mysql_query($query)`.

Comment: Isso é uma function ou stored procedure?

Comment: @ThomsonTorvalds mssql_query é uma função que acessa o SQL Server da Microsoft, um outro banco de dados, que não é o MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Do jeito que está na pergunta, ele já executa, para obter os resultados, pode utilizar o mssql_fetch_array conforme já descrito na resposta anterior.

Aproveitando para indicar a forte possibilidade de SQL Injection neste código, além da depreciação da função no PHP 7.0 - migre para PDO se possível.

Answer (score 1):

Agora é só usar um laço de repetição (while) para trabalhar com os resultados:

```
$result = mssql_query($sql); 
while ($results = mssql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $nome = $results['nome'];
    $endereco = $results['endereco'];
    ...
}
```

Aí você troca os $results[''] pelos campos da sua tabela que deseja utilizar.

Comment: obrigado já consegui era só adicionar
return ($variavel)